# POST data not passed from AJAX to PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

As a test on click I send this from jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    /* Updated new Item */
    $(".CRUD-update").click(function(e) {
        var form_action = $("#update-user").find("form").attr("action");
        alert("HERERERERE");
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: url + form_action,
            data: {
                test: 'Hi there!'
            },
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
                toastr.success('Item Updated Successfully.', 'Success Alert', {
                    timeOut: 5000
                });
            }
        });
         alert("End"); /*Just added. Shouldn't this fire when it is done?*/
    });
});
```

To this php script

```
<?php
   if(isset($_POST['test'])){
       echo "TEST ".$_POST['test'];
   }
   echo "NOT SET";
   echo "USERID ".$_SESSION['user_id'];
}
?>
```

I get no POST data. The alert fires in the jQuery file and my PHP file gets the redirection, just no POST data.

It has been driving me crazy for a couple of days. Any one have any ideas?

Tim

Comment: hardcode this to try out `  url: url + form_action,`

Comment: Did you check the Network tab in your browser ? Also you might need to use `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8;"`

Comment: @AhmadIbrahim but OP isn't sending or expecting JSON

Comment: What is in the alert? And what does *"gets the redirection"* mean? Sounds like you have a form that reloads that same php script and need to prevent default form submit. Try `$(".CRUD-update").click(function(e) { e.preventDefault() /* rest of the code*/`

Comment: above me is the answer. additional: you need to include error: function() too for debugging purpose

Comment: Thank you for the replies. @charlietfl I added e.preventDefault() to the top of the script. I think you were correct in that the form was getting submitted by default. However, nothing seems to happen. As the php file never gets loaded I can't tell if the POST made it there or not.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code and found two things that is breaking it.

- The `url` in `url + form_action` should be removed cause there was never an initial declaration of the `url` variable. You just need to change it to `url: form_action`
- The php receiving the post has a syntax error. You added a close curly brace at the very bottom. I think you might need to add an `else {` before `echo "NOT SET";` to fix this problem.

Note: Looking at your issues above these things could have been avoided if you used a proper code editor. Cause the code editor will automatically catch these issues and save you days of misery.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have fixed those issues and will be using MS Visual Studio Code from now on. Now when I run the code nothing seems to happen. How can I tell if the POST made it to the PHP file? It just seems to be disappear into the internet.

Comment: I put a second alert in the jQuery right at the end of the click function. The first (existing) alert fires, the second one doesn't. Shouldn't it popup another alert as the last thing in the function? Does that mean the code it breaking down somewhere in between?

Comment: It will depend on the location of your php file. it is on the same location as your html file then it won't have issues. another thing to take note is that you are putting your function on a `success` parameter meaning you will only receive the response from php if it's a success, 404 or 500 errors will be discarded. Do make sure your php is working properly by directly executing it on your browser. you can also use postman to test if your post request is working see google extension [postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop/related?hl=en)

Comment: for your second question i am not familiar with the toastr variable you may need to verify if its working properly. do check your browser console to verify if there are issues.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the jquery slim doesn't support ajax. So all those hours of troubleshooting were for nothing. Thanks to all who offered suggestions and help.